# Definition of stress (Mechanical Properties of Solids)

Tags: forces, definition, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, stress-strain

See, it's a simple question.**What exactly is stress?**  Is it the restoring force applied by the body in reaction to deformation force or is it the deformation force itself? I had this doubt because in some videos, they said that stress is the force applied whereas some others said that it's the distribution of internal forces. **Please help me clarifying this doubt!!**

Comment: Stress is the applied force, strain is the resulting deformations.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_(mechanics)

Answer (score 2):

At first, there is the concept of one dimensional stress: $\sigma = \frac{F}{A}$, where $F$ is the applied force and $A$ is the cross section of a longitudinal test probe. By measuring the longitudinal and transverse strain, material properties as elasticity modulus and Poisson coefficient are calculated.

Now, we have what is necessary to deal with a body of any shape and arbitrary loading. The strain of each point can be measured by strain gages for example. With the strain and the material parameters, the stress tensor can be calculated for each point.

So, stress is a tensor, and its determination in a given point for a given material, requires knowledge of material elasticity parameters and measurement (or estimation) of strain.